# how to add custom field option in php form for dynamic value storage

Tags: php, ajax, dynamic

how to make a php form in which user is allowed to add custom field while filling form and data updates in database dynamically..

I already searched a lot on it,  but unfortunately i am unable to get what to use.  i thoight it can be achieved using zend or yii but i am unable to sort it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this in view:

```
<script language="javascript">
function addInput() {
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML += "Field: <input name='alldata[]' type='text' value='' /><br />";

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form">
<input type="button" onclick="addInput()" name="add" value="Add input field" />
</form>
<div id="text">
</div>
```

and you can get all fields in controller like this:

```
<?php foreach($_POST['alldata'] as $row){
echo $row;
echo '<br />';
}?>
```

as you are passing an array of input type=text with name 'alldata'.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  i will try this and will make a reply here.

Comment: @devilcrab no doubt it will work. just put the code where it should be. and if still there is problem, i will help u to figure it out.

Comment: ahhh.   i think i am bit confused can you give a bit more detail on it.